# Can a Vue application be bundled into single html file to be available offline

Tags: javascript, vue.js, d3.js

We have an application that uses VueJs and D3. The requirement for our users is that they wont have internet connection, so they can only accept a html file or a bunch of files(zipped folder).

My first question is if we go ahead with Vue, can we use html-webpack-plugin to bundle everything into a single html file?

My second question is: When I google bundling into a single html, Progressive Web Apps show up in search results. Are PWA's web applications that you can just open an html and it works or Or is PWA more about how to handle a webapp when it does not have access to network?

Thanks!

Comment: One of the features of progressive web apps is the ability of the application to work offline with the usage of a service worker.

Comment: The concern is not about Vue or some other libraries, it's about service worker.

Comment: Ah ok, my question is can i use PWA to develop an app that only works offline? All parts of it are offline